# Controlling valve actuators with PWM signal

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-design, pwm, solenoid-valve

I want to control ME-4340 Syncube Non Spring Return Modulating Valve Actuator - 0/2-10Vdc [ME-4340](https://spartan-pd.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/zone_valves_4140_4240_43401.pdf) with an STM32.

The timer configurated as a PWM generator of the STM32L073RZTx gives 3.3 V at 100% so I used a voltage follower with gain of 4 and an RC filter with a cut-off frequency of 160 Hz.

[image]

The op-amp I am using is the NCS20074DR2G [Datasheet](https://eu.mouser.com/ProductDetail/ON-Semiconductor/NCS20074DR2G?qs=dbuNSGnowt2OktFWnK3k%252Bw%3D%3D). It has a maximum output current of +-100 mA and it is capable of sourcing 60 mA when it is supplied with 10 VDC.

My questions :

- Is this valve even controllable by a PWM signal?
- What is the max. frequency of the PWM signal I can use ?
- What is most crucial factor for the valve ripple voltage or response time of the filter? (for lower cut-off frequency I get less ripple on the other hand the response time increases to about 100 ms.)

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't get why would you use a PWM if you already have a DAC output on STM32. Further, you only control the valve with this signal, the solenoid is driven from valve's electronics, not from you.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič I want to design 8 (0-10V) outputs.

Comment: OK. What a PWM has to do, then? And why are you asking about the PWM frequency that a valve should accept?

Answer (score 2):

> Is this valve even controllable by PWM signal?

Not directly; the ME4**2**40 takes a PWM signal, but the ME4**3**40 takes a voltage of 0 to 10 V (or 2 to 10 V) as the input signal. You can create that voltage from 3.3 V PWM with a low-pass filter followed by an amplifier with a gain of about 3 (or amplify first, then filter), and I assume that is what you are trying to do.

> What is the max frequency of the PWM signal I can use ?

If you low-pass filter the PWM to get an adjustable voltage, then the higher, the better; it makes filtering easier. Go for the highest PWM frequency you can make with the STM32 that still gives you enough resolution.

> What is most crucial factor for the valve, ripple voltage or response time of the filter?

It would depends on how fast you want the valve to react (and I don't expect them to be lightning-quick), but the higher the frequency of your PWM is, the higher the cut-off frequency of your low-pass filter can be, making it faster without much ripple. I have no idea what amount of ripple that valve actuator can endure, but I doubt it will be a problem if you set things up right. Also, nothing is stopping you from making a steeper filter should you need it, but I doubt you will.

Comment: Interesting point: "what amount of ripple that valve actuator can endure", why is this a factor? Voltage swing? Mechanical oscillations? I assume you mean ripple in the step response, or is it residual PWM ripple?.

Comment: Ripple on the valve actuators input signal voltage. No idea what's inside these valve actuators, and how they react to ripple (size/frequency). It isn't specced, but I doubt very much it will be a problem (unless the ripple is very large and low-frequency enough to move the valve constantly, or make the input voltage go too far over the specced 10V sometimes).

Comment: Ok, got it. Thanks!